# ListLinePlot3D to visualize a scatter plot of the first 100 triplets generated from the digits of Pi

Tags: plotting

Use ListLinePlot3D to visualize a scatter plot of the first 100 triplets generated from the digits of Pi. (Hint: Use RealDigits to find the digits of Pi and Partition to group them into sets of 3 for the x,y,z coordinates. Set Filling to Bottom and ColorFunction to "Rainbow").

Expected output:

[image]

In the process of solving the above problem. Here is my solution:

Input:
RealDigits [Pi,10,100]

Output:
{{3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5,3,5,8,9,7,9,3,2,3,8,4,6,2,6,4,3,3,8,3,2,7,9,5,0,2,8,8,4,1,9,7,1,6,9,3,9,9,3,7,5,1,0,5,8,2,0,9,7,4,9,4,4,5,9,2,3,0,7,8,1,6,4,0,6,2,8,6,2,0,8,9,9,8,6,2,8,0,3,4,8,2,5,3,4,2,1,1,7,0,6,7},1}

To partition into 3:

Input:    Partition[{3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5,3,5,8,9,7,9,3,2,3,8,4,6,2,6,4,3,3,8,3,2,7,9,5,0,2,8,8,4,1,9,7,1,6,9,3,9,9,3,7,5,1,0,5,8,2,0,9,7,4,9,4,4,5,9,2,3,0,7,8,1,6,4,0,6,2,8,6,2,0,8,9,9,8,6,2,8,0,3,4,8,2,5,3,4,2,1,1,7,0,6,7},3]

Output:
{{3,1,4},{1,5,9},{2,6,5},{3,5,8},{9,7,9},{3,2,3},{8,4,6},{2,6,4},{3,3,8},{3,2,7},{9,5,0},{2,8,8},{4,1,9},{7,1,6},{9,3,9},{9,3,7},{5,1,0},{5,8,2},{0,9,7},{4,9,4},{4,5,9},{2,3,0},{7,8,1},{6,4,0},{6,2,8},{6,2,0},{8,9,9},{8,6,2},{8,0,3},{4,8,2},{5,3,4},{2,1,1},{7,0,6}}

Input:

```
ListLinePlot3D[{{3,1,4},{1,5,9},{2,6,5},{3,5,8},{9,7,9},{3,2,3},{8,4,6},{2,6,4},{3,3,8},{3,2,7},{9,5,0},{2,8,8},{4,1,9},{7,1,6},{9,3,9},{9,3,7},{5,1,0},{5,8,2},{0,9,7},{4,9,4},{4,5,9},{2,3,0},{7,8,1},{6,4,0},{6,2,8},{6,2,0},{8,9,9},{8,6,2},{8,0,3},{4,8,2},{5,3,4},{2,1,1},{7,0,6}}, Filling -> Bottom, ColorFunction ->"Rainbow"]
```

Final output:

[image]

This varies from the expected output.

After replacing ListLinePlot3D with ListPointPlot3D, getting output in points, but the number of points appear lesser than the one provided by the instructor.

[image]

Comment: Looks like your instructions contains a typo (Your instructor must have meant `ListPointPlot3D` or he/she used the wrong picture for expected output).

Comment: Regarding the number of points: You are grouping 100 numbers into 33 triplets (whereas you need 100 triplets)